# Read jpeg metadata with jai-imageio-jpeg2000

Tags: java, jpeg, exif, javax.imageio, jpeg2000

I want to read some jpeg metadata like width, height, color depth and resolution with [jai-imageio-jpeg2000](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000) library. Is there any example for it?

Comment: It's a little unclear why you want to use a JPEG 2000 library to read JPEG metadata? Also, what have you tried so far? What does not work?

Comment: If you aren't tied to that library, perhaps try using [metadata-extractor](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/).